# TS-Jest; how to remove linter errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, tslint

We are running a project with typescript and are now looking into adding tests. Are we able to use TS-jest with types, or do we need to use `any`? Right now we get linter errors if we use mock.

An example:

```
const emit: Emit = jest.fn()

callFunctionWithEmit(emit)

expect(emit.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual({
  result: null
})
```

This works, but the linter tells us that Emit doesn't have a mock-property. Is there any good ways to remove these linter-errors?

We're using VSCode together with these plugins:

- Prettier
- TSLint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this is to use jest.Mock.

The solution would look like this:

```
const emit: jest.Mock<Emit> = jest.fn()

callFunctionWithEmit(emit)

expect(emit.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual({
   result: null
})
```